# how to scroll to beginning/end of scroll buffer in tmux?

Tags: scroll, tmux

^b+page up/down scrolls up/down one page of scroll buffer, but how do we scroll to beginning ?

like wise with end (besides pressing ^C to kill scrolling)

Comment: why the downvote? this question is hard to find an answer to (every related question only asks about page up/down)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This depends on the binding of "mode-keys". If you have `set-option -g mode-keys emacs` in your ~/.tmux.conf file (actually, this should be the default), then you can go to the beginning and the end of the buffer using corresponding emacs keys:

1. Enter the copy mode using: <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
2. Go to the beginning using: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (or, in emacs' notation: M-<)

Similarly, going to the end is achieved by M->

If instead you prefer vi keybindings, you can put `set-option -g mode-keys vi` in your ~/.tmux.conf file, and then you have:

1. Enter the copy mode using: <kbd>ctrl-b</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
2. Go to the beginning using `gg`, go to the bottom using `G`

Please note that configuration in ~/.tmux.conf only takes effect after the tmux server restarts. That is when you kill all sessions and then restart tmux.

Comment: This works on 1 laptop (mac) but not on another mac. I did also add 'set-option -g mode-keys emacs' in ~/.tmux.conf just to make sure. How would i change key binding to 'h' instead of Alt+shift+, (just to try if that works) ?

Comment: You can change copy-mode key bindings with the -t parameter to bind-key.  For instance, `bind-key -t vi-copy Home history-top` and `bind-key -t vi-copy End history-bottom` (or emacs-copy if you use emacs mode) make it easy to get to the top and bottom of history.

Comment: seems to default to vi mode... so `gg` for top `G` for bottom

Comment: @JonnyRaa that also only scrolls back to the end of the buffer (for `G`) btw in case anyone wondering how to just jump back to the dang input. The easiest method if that's what you're looking for (which I was) is to just press `q`, which exits scroll mode and puts you back to the terminal input (without killing off mouse mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode C-S-Home send -X history-top # Ctrl+Shift+Home
bind-key -T copy-mode C-S-End send -X history-bottom # Ctrl+Shift+End
```

This way when you are in copy mode <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Home</kbd> will take you to the beginning of scroll buffer and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+End</kbd> will take you to the end of scroll buffer.